Prove website performance is due to the shared hosting provider server
Starting 11/09/2024 my website performance decreased after the hosting provider migrated the site to a cloud-based server.
The issue occurs when transitioning from HTTP to HTTPS (about 1 or 2 seconds) and between the initial user URL request and the execution of the page's PHP script (from 0.5 to 20+ seconds).
Before that date, pages loaded in less then 300 milliseconds. They are  simple php script generating static html (99% text).
The issue occurs randomly even when accessing a very simple page containing only 10 pure html lines, without any php statement inside it and with no redirect or other stuff.
How can I gather evidence to prove that the website slow performance is due to the hosting provider server?
Edit: moved at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/145721/prove-that-my-websites-slowness-is-due-to-the-hosting-providers-server

@NikitaKipriyanov I don't need to test the server capacity but only the two issues I explained in my post. It's only about the server response speed. Also due to the fact that is a web hosting, I cannot install anything.

First, you should rule out any problem with your PHP scripting. Test using static HTML pages with and w/o SSL and then progress to specific test scripts, testing one aspect at a time (with and w/o SQL access etc.).

Show them your performance testing data and results.

@Zac67 the slow performance occur also with the simplest php file containing exactly ONLY some html (e.g. a list of text)

@GregAskew already done since that date but they reply with useless and dump solutions (like "rise the php max input vars...)

Well, you always have the option to switch to a different hoster if you are not satisfied.

@GeraldSchneider for sure! Except that I already paid for some future years of subscription :-( So now I must prove their fault in order to get my money back.

So the proof would be the your performance testing data and results, that would show the server is slow, and not your code, because there is no code. For example, run a benchmark (even something like ab will suffice) and measure the load during that run, and show them that load is high while the throughput is low or the delays are awfully high, or something like this. Well, show some performance benchmark already, because it isn't possible to suggest anything without having at least some concrete numbers.

@NikitaKipriyanov I signed up in pingdom and set some automated test for "page speed" and "status up", after some days I'll have some data. I'll try ab if it is available without install anything server side (I can't on a shared web hosting). thanks

I suspected that. You should have been telling from the very beginning this is all about shared hosting. Well, I doubt you'll be able to properly measure the server load on the shared hosting, and that we'll be able to help you here. Basically, if you don't have a root shell access to the server, ServerFault is not for you; probably you can have more luck on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

@NikitaKipriyanov posted on webmasters (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/145721/prove-that-my-websites-slowness-is-due-to-the-hosting-providers-server), thanks, I should delete this one?

No, it'll be automatically deleted.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement

@GregAskew I can't find the SLA for register_dot_it/?lang=en web shared hosting on their website
